Maximum subgraph of a strongly regular graph satisfying cohomology constraints
Consider the following strongly regular graph $G=(V,E)$ (constructed as the symplectic graph over $\mathbb F_2^{2r}$) with $r>1$ with parameters
$$
(n,k,a,c)=\left( 2^{2r}-1,2^{2r-1},2^{2r-2},2^{2r-2} \right) 
$$
Consider a subgraph $U \subset G$ with vertices $V_U$ and edges $E_U$, i.e., $U=(V_U,E_U)$ and a value assignment $\gamma:V_U \to \mathbb{F}_{2}$ on each vertex of the subgraph.
Define a 2-cocycle $\beta(a,b)=\gamma(a)+\gamma(b)-\gamma(a+b)$
which satisfies conditions $d\beta=0$ and $[\beta]=0$.
What is the size of the largest possible subgraph to satisfy these conditions?

Chain complex
Define a chain complex $(C_\bullet,\partial_\bullet)$ as follows:

$C_0(V_U)=\mathbb Z_2$
$C_1(V_U)$ is the free $\mathbb Z_2$ module generated by the vertices $a_k\in V_U$ of the subgraph $U(V_U,E_U)$
$C_2(V_U)$  is the free $\mathbb Z_2$ module generated by the edges $(a_j,a_k)\in E_U$ of the graph $U(V_U,E_U)$, corresponding to $a_j,a_k\in V_U$ such that $a_j,a_k$ satisfy the symplectic condition.
$C_3(V_U)$ is the free $\mathbb Z_2$ module generated by triples $(a_j,a_k,a_l)$ such that $[a_j|a_k],[a_j|a_l],[a_k|a_l]\in C_2(V_U)$

The boundary operator takes

$\partial_{1} [a_{j}]=0$
$\partial_{2}[a_{j}|a_{k}]=[a_{k}]-[a_{j}+a_{k}]+[a_{j}]$
$\partial_{3}[a_{j}|a_{k}|a_{l}]=[a_{k}|a_{l}]-[a_{j}+a_{k}|a_{l}]+[a_{j}|a_{k}+a_{l}]-[a_{j}|a_{k}]$

Define a cochain $C^\bullet(V_U)$ where each $C^n(V_U)$ are $\mathbb Z_2$-linear maps $C_n(V_U)\to \mathbb Z_2$.
The coboundary operator is defined as $dc=c\partial$ for $c\in C^n(V_U)$.
Specifically, (for $C^1(V_U)$) define $\gamma:V_U\to\mathbb Z_2$ as a 1-cochain and (for $C^2(V_U)$) define $\beta$, defined in terms of $\gamma$ above, as a 2-cochain.
We have the condition that $d\beta=0$ which means it is a 2-cocycle.
$$d\beta(a_{j},a_{k},a_{l}])=\beta(a_{k},a_{l})-\beta(a_{j}+a_{k},a_{l})+\beta(a_{j},a_{k}+a_{l})-\beta(a_{j},a_{k})=0$$
and $[\beta]=0$, which is the cohomology class of the 2-cocycle $\beta$. Specifically,
$$[\beta]=\{\beta+dx, \quad \forall x \in C^1(C(V_U))\}$$

What is $[\beta]$? How is that computed from $\beta$? Similarly, how to I get $d\beta$? Does that come from the symplectic geometry?

@KenW.Smith I have now added an explanation of the (co)chain complex and associated 2-cocycle and boundary operators

I'm sorry, but this is not helpful. What do these co-cycle definitions have to do with an underlying graph? (How do these definitions interact with edges?) At this point, I see two mathematical concepts: chain complexes and graphs, yet no clear connection between them. I don't think this problem is well-defined.
